# Access directory by modification date

Tags: files, directory, timestamps

Is there a way to refer to a directory by its modification date, like `cd ~/$newest/subdirectory`? I know that I could (and shouldn't?) parse `ls`, and I currently just use a hacky script that generates symlinks. Short of writing a filesystem is there any way to do this?

For clarity I would like it to act like an actual folder so I can use it in paths in various contexts, i.e. outside bash.

Comment: Can't you adjust the script/program that creates the directory to also update the symlink, that is how programs like `py.test` give you a link to the latest test-run, while keeping N older runs available.

Comment: Well that's what I currently do, for a symlink called `latest`. I could even call it `latest0` and then iterate over `latest*` and increment each. Unfortunately not all the folders are created by the script anymore but some are copied in from elsewhere. Ideally I'd get a general purpose solution, or a strong claim that it's impossible.

Comment: There is no creation date, unless your vendor has added something to the traditional `stat(2)` call (e.g. on Mac OS X) or otherwise stored that information somewhere in the filesystem (ext attributes?).

Comment: @thrig: ext4 has [`crtime`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L696) - aka birth-time , (unless, for some reason, such as fs being <512 MiB, the inode size is old size (of 128 bytes)). `stat`, at least on Linux, does however not populate this value and one need root privileges to access it, (by e.g. debugfs). Status? IDK http://superuser.com/a/703927/189803 - but it has been 5 years :P

Comment: Since I hadn't been modifying my data I wasn't drawing a distinction. For simplicity I've changed the question to modification time.

Comment: Two options I see: 1. A custom FS (probably FUSE) that does the lookup for you. Difficult, and probably overkill. 2. A background script that watches the directory via inotify and updates links automatically. Probably the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a skeleton of a shell script:

```
while inotifywait $some_dir -e create; do
    read _ fname < <(find $some_dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n -k1,1 | tail -n1)
    ln -sf $fname $some_dir/latest
done
```

(Requires GNU `find`; there's probably some POSIX way to do it, or you could parse `ls`, or...)

Set this to running in the background, and whenever a directory is created, the symlink `latest` will be updated to point to the newest mtime directory.